# How do I get the bottom two boxes to stack one another in mobile size?

Tags: html, css

I have tried using different flex properties including flex-grow/shrink/basis/wrap and media queries but I'm unable to stack the last box below when the screen gets smaller (ex: 678px) and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I want to use only flexbox and not grid, float, etc. to complete this.
I'm trying to completely understand how to use flexbox so any help is deeply appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-top"></div>
    <div class="container-bottom">
      <div class="inner-container subscription">
      <div class="inner-container reasons">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #e6eff6;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* flex-basis refers to height here since body's (parent) flex-direction is column. */
  flex: 0 0 430px;
  max-width: 600px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #c3ced6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.container-top {
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem 2rem 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container-bottom {
  display: flex;
  height: 60%;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
}

.inner-container {
  padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
}

.inner-container.subscription {
  background-color: #2bb3b1;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.inner-container.reasons {
  background-color: #4abebd;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Look into this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding `media queries` and `flex-direction: row` to `container`

```
@media (max-width: 680px) {
   .container {
     flex-direction:row;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but this is what happens.
https://responsive-content.vercel.app/

Comment: increasing the height only way to stack the box below without increasing height unable to stack the box below

Comment: below i am adding code the code check out that

Answer (score 0):

remove this query

```
@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .container {
     flex-direction:row;
  }
 }
```

remove the `display:flex` in  `container-bottom`

```
.container-bottom {
       height: 60%;
  }
```

add `1` to flex value

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex: 1 0 430px; #adding 1 to flex
   max-width: 600px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #c3ced6;
   border-radius: 6px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 2rem;
```

}

or remove `flex` and add `height` to container

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height : 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #c3ced6;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 2rem;
}
```

both will result in

[image]